# Selling digital goods on Facebook Messenger Platform

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm developing a FB Messenger bot which is technically a turn-based game. I want to sell in-game goods for real money through FB Payments or 3rd party service like XSola, for example.

But it seems like according to FB policy selling virtual good on Messenger platform is not allowed:
https://developers.facebook.com/policy - 16.6.5.d

> d. Don't use Messenger Platform to sell digital goods.

I want to be sure whether this policy is applicable to my case or not. FB support basically told me they can't resolve my issue at this point:

> Thank you for contacting Facebook.
>
> It looks like your inquiry requires some technical or policy assistance and is not directly related to the payments you receive for in-app earnings on the Facebook Platform. Unfortunately, our team is not able to provide support for Platform policy or technical support inquiries.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would it not be applicable on your case?

Comment: _“I want to be sure whether this policy is applicable to my case or not.”_ – well that’s easy, just answer one single question: Are you using the Messenger Platform …? There’s your answer then.

Comment: Try another department at facebook (if you tried bot they try payments and the converse). Retry the department you reached out to in a new request.